# reference this assignation in copy constructor

Tags: c++, reference, this

Hi what is the meaning of this line in this copy contructor?

`*this = ref`

```
Test::Test(const Test &ref){
  *this = ref;
}
```

Comment: What part is not clear? Do you know the meaning of `this` etc?

Comment: Look at the copy assignment operator (`Test& Test::operator=(const Test&);`). What does that look like? Please put that into the question too.

Comment: Unrelated: there are often advantages to implementing the other way around with the assignment operator based on the copy constructor. See [What is the copy-and-swap idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543) for a detailed discussion.